# Windows 7 x64 bug on EnumWindow?

Tags: delphi

see the simple Delphi code here :

```
function EnumProc(Handle: THandle; Lparam: LPARAM): Bool; stdcall;
begin
  TMemo(Lparam).Lines.Add(IntToStr(Handle));
end;
```

call it :

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnumWindows(@EnumProc, Lparam(Memo1))
end;
```

This code work successfully in Windows XP , Window 7 x86 and Windows 8 .

now test the code in Windows 7 x64, it only return one item , it means windows just one time call EnumProc , it means the result of EnumProc is false and no more window available to enumerate on it ...

now change our EnumProc to :

```
function EnumProc(Handle: THandle; Lparam: LPARAM): Bool; stdcall;
begin
  TMemo(Lparam).Lines.Add(IntToStr(Handle));
  result:= True;
end;
```

Ok , how about this ?! it will work on any version of Windows include Windows 7 x64 !

Any idea ? is it a bug in Windows or wrong thing in my code ?

Regards Mojtaba .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a problem with your code. In your first example, you define a function that returns a `Bool` and you fail to return anything. You're just lucky it works at all. I'm surprised it compiles without warning you.

As the [documentation says](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Function_Declarations)

> If the function exits without assigning a value to **Result** or the function name, then the function's return value is undefined.

Your second (correct) example doesn't have this problem therefore it works fine, which is not surprising.